# Error in checking my mouse position on my canvas (Pygame)

Tags: python, tuples, pygame

My code is supposed to check my mouse position then print it but it only checks it once, whats the issue?

```
import pygame, sys, time 
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption ('get POS')

while True:
    amntTuple = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print (amntTuple)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [pygame.event.get()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) to get new events from the pygame event queue.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
        amntTuple = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        print (amntTuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to establish a [mouse motion event handler](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) and set up a proper pygame event processing loop.